# What does this line/syntax mean?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Auto_ptr1
{
    T* m_ptr;
public:
    // Pass in a pointer to "own" via the constructor
    Auto_ptr1(T* ptr=nullptr)
        :m_ptr(ptr)
    {
    }

    // The destructor will make sure it gets deallocated
    ~Auto_ptr1()
    {
        delete m_ptr;
    }

    // Overload dereference and operator-> so we can use Auto_ptr1 like m_ptr.
    T& operator*() const { return *m_ptr; }
    T* operator->() const { return m_ptr; }
};

// A sample class to prove the above works
class Resource
{
public:
    Resource() { std::cout << "Resource acquired\n"; }
    ~Resource() { std::cout << "Resource destroyed\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    Auto_ptr1<Resource> res(new Resource); // Note the allocation of memory here

    // ... but no explicit delete needed

    // Also note that the Resource in angled braces doesn't need a * symbol, since that's supplied by the template

    return 0;
} // res goes out of scope here, and destroys the allocated Resource for us
```

I want to know what does the syntax in this line mean, I have never used it before:

```cpp
Auto_ptr1<Resource> res(new Resource); // Note the allocation of memory here
```

I tried googling for it but there wasn't any results, and even if there were I wouldn't know how to frame the appropriate question, so I hopped on to StackOverflow for this.

Comment: Same as `Resource* temp = new Resource; Auto_ptr1<Resource> res(temp);` Is it clearer this way?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik why is the typename Auto_ptr1 specified? i am not new to c++, am currently learning it. but i havent been introduced to this syntax before so my questions may seem like as if i know know c++ at all but i do its just the syntax. are we trying to create an instance of Auto_ptr1 that is a pointer to Resource object, or is this a vector?

Comment: Are you asking why there's `<Resource>` after `Auto_ptr1`? You may wish to read about templates in your favorite C++ textbook.

Answer (score 1):

- `Auto_ptr1` looks like a (poor) reimplementation of [C++ STL's `unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).
- So it's a "smart-pointer" that limits the lifetime of the heap-allocated data pointed-to by `m_ptr` by the lifetime of the parent `Auto_ptr1` instance.

Breaking it down:

```
Auto_ptr1<Resource> res(new Resource);
```

Does this:

1. Allocates memory for an instance of `Resource` using the default allocator for `new` (i.e. the OS-provided heap).
2. The address to that new `Resource` instance is passed into the constructor for `Auto_ptr1`.

   - Which is then stored in `m_ptr` inside the `res` value.
3. When `res` goes out-of-scope, the destructor for the `Resource` instance will be invoked.

I appreciate that this looks like a learning-exercise, which is fine and I encourage more people to reimplement standard library components to learn about how they work and to develop an appreciation for them - but I don't recommend using this code in production (because that's what the peer-reviewed STL and Boost libraries are for).

Answer (score 0):

As @Igor Tandetnik said, it creates an instance of a [class template](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/templates-cpp/) `Auto_ptr1` with type `Resource` called `res` which it initializes with a pointer to a new dynamically allocated `Resource`.